# How do I annotate a class that extends a HashMap for XML Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How do I annotate a class that extends a HashMap for XML Marshalling using JAXB.

This example code

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExampleMap extends HashMap<String,String>{

   public String group= "Test Group";

}
```

Produces this xml

```
<ExampleMap>
  <group>Test Group</group>
</ExampleMap>
```

I can modify the class to this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExampleMap extends HashMap<String,String>{

    public String group= "Test Group";
    public Map<String,String> self = this;

}
```

and I now get

```
<ExampleMap>
  <group>Test Group</group>
  <self>
    <entry><key>2</key><value>2</value></entry>
    <entry><key>1</key><value>1</value></entry>
  </self>
</ExampleMap>
```

Which is the result I want, but using that self referencing `Map<String,String> self = this;` feels wrong.

How should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that although it felt wrong, it is in fact a bonafide way of doing it.
Although this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152683/3696510 uses a get method to return 'this' the results are the same.